# Почему не выбирается значение в select-e

Tags: golang

https://gobyexample.com/non-blocking-channel-operations

В примере указанном по этой ссылке:

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
    messages := make(chan string)
    signals := make(chan bool)

    select {
    case msg := <-messages:
        fmt.Println("received message", msg)
    default:
        fmt.Println("no message received")
    }


    msg := "hi"
    select {
    case messages <- msg:
        fmt.Println("sent message", msg)
    default:
        fmt.Println("no message sent")
    }

    select {
    case msg := <-messages:
        fmt.Println("received message", msg)
    case sig := <-signals:
        fmt.Println("received signal", sig)
    default:
        fmt.Println("no activity")
    }
}
```

Выводится:

```
no message received
no message sent
no activity
```

Отсюда вопрос: **почему не попадаем в этот блок?**

```
case messages <- msg:
    fmt.Println("sent message", msg)
```

Ведь выше мы записываем в `msg` строку `"hi"`

Answer (score 1):

## Потому что отправляемое сообщение некому принять.

В Go по умолчанию каналы **не буфферизованные** и не удерживают сообщений, которые не могут немедленно доставить. Поэтому **обычная** операция отправки в этом случае заблокирует поток (пока получатель не появится).

А реализация **неблокирующей** отправки `select`ом в этой ситуации передаёт управление на метку `default` и **не** отправляет сообщение.

Посмотрите пояснение к [примеру по многопоточности](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2):

> By default, sends and receives block until the other side is ready. This allows goroutines to synchronize without explicit locks or condition variables.

> По умолчанию, операции отправки и получения блокируются, пока другая сторона не будет готова. Это позволяет горутинам синхронизироваться без явных блокировок или переменных для условий.

Comment: Спасибо что откликнулись, прошу поясните пожалуйста, а в 3-ем select-e      он не видит получателя из-за разных областей видимости? Вот тут case msg := <-messages:
        fmt.Println("received message", msg)

Comment: @Kenshi то же самое, во все эти каналы никто ничего в этот момент не отправляет.